# Can I merge text into irregular shapes? Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text, merge

I've made irregular shapes by overlaying white squares over each-other randomly and now I want to make it so that my text fits perfectly within those irregular shapes as one whole continuous paragraph. Is it possible to do this without making multiple text boxes? This is in adobe illustrator. Thank you (:

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with pretty much any *closed* shape/ path except "Compound Paths".
You can draw an irregular shape with the pen tool and as long as it is a closed path you can fill it with Area Type.

For your squares select them and open the Pathfinder Panel (Window> Pathfinder) and hit the Unite icon (upper left). This will create one shape from your different objects. Then choose the Type Tool (T) and click on the outline of the newly created path. This will place your cursor inside the shape and you can type into it or paste text into it.

You can also modify your Area Text Box shape after the text is inserted by moving line segments or anchor points.

Comment: You can do holes as well ([see here](https://www.dummies.com/software/adobe/illustrator/wrap-text-in-adobe-illustrator-cc/)) with text warp objects ([see example picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nBy0G.png))

Comment: Thank you @joojaa- of course- a text wrap object inside an area type box rather than a compound path- very good !

Comment: Sounds like the OP want's *constrained* text, as Kyle has outlined in this answer. That's *wrapped* text @joojaa Not the same thing.

Comment: @Scott yeah i just pointed out that the holes can be  done with wrap, so you dont actually need the compound path functionality. Also wraps can be used to constrain by flipping the side,  but thats a different thing